# not start trigger on view from pg_stat_activity

Tags: postgresql, view, triggers

In postgres not real create trigger on pg_stat_activity, becouse i create my view based on pg_stat_activity and create trigger.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_sa() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS f_call_count_conn();
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS f_update_count_conn();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_sa() RETURNS SETOF pg_stat_activity AS
$$ SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity; $$
LANGUAGE sql
VOLATILE
SECURITY DEFINER;


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW pg_stat_activity_allusers AS SELECT * FROM get_sa();

GRANT SELECT ON pg_stat_activity_allusers TO public;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_call_count_conn()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
      COPY (SELECT time_change, count FROM count_conn) TO '/tmp/query.csv' (format csv, delimiter ';');
      RETURN NEW;
  ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
      COPY (SELECT time_change, count FROM count_conn) TO '/tmp/query.csv' (format csv, delimiter ';');
      RETURN OLD;
  END IF;

  -- PERFORM f_update_count_conn();
  -- RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER t_check_activity_conn
INSTEAD OF INSERT OR DELETE ON pg_stat_activity_allusers
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE f_call_count_conn();


CREATE FUNCTION f_update_count_conn()
  RETURNS VOID
AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  insert into count_conn (time_change, count)
    values (NOW(), (select count(*)
    from pg_stat_activity_allusers));
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

This code is not working, but when i replace my view (pg_stat_activity_allusers) on real table and change this table, my trigger work. Why? Thank you!

Comment: pg_stat_activity is not table and there are no any events (like insert / update ) happened on it. What do you want?

Comment: when pg_stat_activity change (insert or delete) write to my table info about this change. i know what pg_stat_activity view. official postgres documentation prefer use INSTEAD OF INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE for Views.

Comment: pg_stat_activity is not table - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/monitoring-stats.html You can not catch insert/delete on it. May be you want to log queries? Or user login/logout?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: more than - even pg_stat_activity would be a table, your construction -- view pg_stat_activity_allusers can catch trigger on insert / delete ONLY IF YOU INSERT INTO pg_stat_activity_allusers, not when data in pg_stat_acvtivity changed.

Comment: but my view(pg_stat_activity_allusers) link with pg_stat_activity, because when pg_stat_activity change - change and pg_stat_activity_allusers. i see the same results in two views.

Comment: The logic of view is different. View is just like photo - it only reflect the current state (picture) of the object (table). But no one changes of parent table(s) not call any trigger on view. Trigger than you can create for such view starts only if you _directly_ call insert or delete or update on your view.

Comment: ok, i understand, how realistic is to create a trigger that check add/delete new connection and collect this information? i dont have problem with collect information, main question link with check new connection.Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code worked for me on Postgres 9.5, except I manually called f_update_count_conn() to populate count_conn, because you're not (or no longer) calling it anywhere.

```
# select f_update_count_conn();
 f_update_count_conn 
---------------------

(1 row)

mw=# select * from count_conn;
        time_change         | count 
----------------------------+-------
 2017-02-03 17:22:34.846179 |     1
(1 row)

mw=# insert into pg_stat_activity_allusers(datid) values(123456::oid);
INSERT 0 1
mw=# 
[1]+  Stopped                 '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin'/psql -p5432
$ cat /tmp/query.csv
2017-02-03 17:22:34.846179;1
```

Comment: Thank you! i understand my problem:)

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you want, but the commented-out line in your trigger function `PERFORM f_update_count_conn();` will never get called, because your function returns first.

Comment: but COPY (SELECT time_change, count FROM count_conn) TO '/tmp/query.csv' (format csv, delimiter ';'); not start too. because for me need change pg_stat_activity_allusers. when i make insert into pg_stat_activity_allusers(datid) values(123456::oid); all work.

Comment: What do you mean by you need to "change pg_stat_activity_allusers"? The COPY statement will run on INSERT or DELETE of the view.

Comment: i thought what when change pg_stat_sctivity my view(change pg_stat_activity_allusers) change to and start trigger, but this does not happen, even though the pg_stat_activity_allusers is changed. Create trigger on pg_stat_activity unreal because this view have permission, which doesn't bypass. i found in internet what my view based on pg_stat_activity help, but i was wrong. I see you answer and help @Roman Tkachuk and understand my problem. Thank you!